# Valor hash SHA-1 del nodo directorio o árbol raíz de un commit

Tags: git, hash, sha1

¿Existe alguna manera de obtener el **valor hash SHA-1** del objeto árbol raíz o directorio raíz asociado a un determinado *commit*?

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de obtener el valor **hash SHA-1** del objeto árbol raíz asociado a un determinado *commit* sería usando el comando `git cat-file`. Por ejemplo:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD
tree c03ddaf065209cec8d890c68fd8b20d61c3e5688
parent 799ebb83bdad99476419ee1284644abba538c033
...
```

En la salida, *tree* representa el nodo árbol raíz del *commit* (*HEAD* en este caso).

Otra manera para conseguir este valor hash SHA-1 sería obteniendo primero la ruta del directorio raíz del repositorio, lo que se puede hacer de varias maneras:

- Usando `git rev-parse` dentro del repositorio (fuera de cualquier submódulo en caso de haber):
  `$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
  `/[..]/directorio_raiz_repo/`
- Creando un alias que obtenga esta ruta, aprovechando que los alias sobre comandos de la terminal se ejecutan siempre desde el directorio raíz del repositorio, sin importar la ruta dentro del mismo donde nos encontremos:
  `$ git config --global --add alias.dirraiz '!pwd'`
  `$ git dirraiz`
  `/[..]/directorio_raiz_repo/`

Una vez obtenida la ruta del directorio raíz del repositorio, se vuelve a ejecutar el comando `git rev-parse` sobre ese mismo directorio en el *commit* deseado:

```
$ cd /[..]/directorio_raiz_repo/
$ git rev-parse HEAD:./   [Encontrándonos en el directorio raíz]
c03ddaf065209cec8d890c68fd8b20d61c3e5688
```

Dando el mismo valor hash SHA-1 que el obtenido anteriormente para el mismo *commit*.